# Docker Mapping Same Port On Two Containers To Different Ports On Host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have the following `docker-compose` setup:

```
db:
  image: postgres:10.5-alpine

adminer:
  image: adminer:4.6.3
  ports:
    - 8080:8086

my-service:
  image: my-image:latest
  ports:
    - 8080:8080
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: for adminer  Cannot start service adminer: driver failed programming
  external connectivity on endpoint docker_adminer_1
  (dcd0d56d58bbbefdea89dc64532854597fcaec9736d7ddb3f8de74bc1577d5ee):
  Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated
```

I must be misunderstanding docker networking. I thought because, I'm mapping the `8080` port on the two services to different host ports viz. `8080` and `8086`, I thought I shouldn't have conflicts. I can't seem to be able to locate the relevant documentation on the web.

Can you guys please help me remedy this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it backwards.

`<host_port>:<service_port>` and not the other way around. Switch the numbers and you ought to be fine, but make sure your services are expecting traffic on those new ports.

Edit: [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/compose/compose-file/#ports)